# Examining Magento's final XML structure

Tags: magento

Anyway to examine the final XML structure magento comes up with after parsing & combining all the different XML files?

1. There is nothing of that sort which turned up on searching on the internet and I think for someone like me, magento layouts were a bit too much in the beginning & I would try to do everything on the code side.
2. Another thing which will help in picking up the name of different nodes that we can use, right away from the final XML structure.
3. Never ran into this but I believe we will have a better picture of what's overriding what.

Comment: I've never seen this attempted.  I know that there are a lot of controllers available freely out there that would set you on the right path, but being that Magento is so compartmentalized, I would think there is no "easy" solution.

Comment: I have downvoted this Q because it is open-ended and shows no effort. I do think it is a potentially interesting topic.

Comment: @clockworkgeek Shouldn't you downvote what doesn't qualify as a good question? And if this is interesting, then why downvote it? I don't have the magento mojo to do something like that but it will certainly help in learning. Keep your downvote if you disagree.

Comment: @Zak I think it shouldn't be that hard. Magento keeps a cache of that XML structure too, so should not be that hard for someone with the right skills.

Comment: @Ashfame you have +1 from me if you edit your answer and just make it more clear ... it will nice if there is some example, what actually you don't understand and etc. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following will get you the merged configuration from `app/etc/*.xml`, `app/etc/modules/*.xml`, as well as each (active) module's `config.xml` file; when retrieving the config though there is no indication of what was overwritten, as the merges happen as each config file is being parsed:

```
Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->asNiceXml(); // or asXML() | asArray() | etc.
```

However, you seem to be asking about how the application *makes use of* this information. This is a function of application design.

Also, you mention "all of the different XML files." It's worth noting that these are not maintained in one massive object instance. For example, layout XML is accessed using the layout update object `Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update` and can be accessed *meaningfully* after it's been loaded and manipulated for a given rendering scope (e.g. `loadLayout()` in a controller action):

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->asString(); // or asSimplexml() or asArray()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes - Commercebug.  As well as a whole load of other useful features, you can also view the entire XML structure that Magento has produced.

http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/commerce-bug-2

Comment: Great! Was this in v1? I think I have a copy.

Comment: Yes, it's in v1 (that's what I've got).  There's a Layout tab which shows you the full XML structure :)

Comment: Also, displaying the layout merge was one of the first module demonstrations Alan Storm submitted over on the magentocommerce.com website. It's been highly valuable and was the basis for me purchasing commerce bug.

Comment: Commerce Bug's the best way to peek at the Layout XML files, but there's nothing in there fore viewing the "global configuration" tree Magento builds up.  If you want to learn how to do this yourself, start here for the global config: http://alanstorm.com/magento_config, here for the layout viewer: http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates, and here for a long, step by step journey to the center of Magento's configuration loading: http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_config (all self links)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following will output the XML:  `echo Mage::getConfig()->getXmlString();`

You can create a script with something like this:

```
header("Content-Type:text/xml");

require_once '../app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();

echo Mage::getConfig()->getXmlString();
```

Comment: Where is this method defined?

Comment: @benmarks: Varien_Simplexml_Config, and it essentially calls the code you mentioned, so it's basically just a short cut.

Answer (score 0):

based on answer from benmarks I did

```
echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars(Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->asNiceXml())."</pre>";
```

If you want for example to see the blocks configuration in Magento 1 you can put this in a file, place the file at the root of the site and navigate to it in a browser:

```
<?php
include("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app(); 

//just see blocks...
echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars(Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->global->blocks->asNiceXml())."</pre>";
die();
```